# Thumbnails Not Centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am working with `col-sm-3` sized thumbnails and they are currently not centered aligned (They are left aligned). [image: Problem] I want them evenly space and center aligned. I have been playing with the offsets and push, but can never get exactly evenly spaced.

[image: Second Picture]

I always end up having the spacing between either the sides of the site not the same as the other spacing between the thumbnails.

How can I get the thumbnails evenly spaced and center aligned? Heres my code snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .thumbnail {
        border: 0 none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    div.center
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<div class="row center">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Community Driven</h3>
                <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Community Driven</h3>
                <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Community Driven</h3>
                <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The center tag is deprecated.. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center

Comment: @Daniel still same issue though

Comment: What do you exactly mean with evenly spaced and center aligned? Should they take up all 12 columns / the full width of the container, and should the left icon be left aligned, the center icon center aligned and the right icon right aligned?

Comment: Post your CSS for these tags ..

Comment: @ckuijjer I want the center one in the center of the screen and the left and right ones evenly spaced from the sides of the side and from the center one. I am not quite sure how the grid system works. I read up on it but still don't get it

Comment: I noted that you try to reset the styling on the `.thumbnail` class. Why not simply use `.col-sm-4`, use a `<div>` without the `.thumbnail` class and add some horizontal padding to it?

Comment: Yup thats exactly what I wanted! Thanks! If you put that as an answer Ill mark it as correct for future references

Comment: Hehe, look what kind of horrible solution I just though of below. I'll update it with the simpler trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstraps grid is based on 12 columns. It divides every `.row` into 12 columns, and using columns classes like `.col-xs-6` or `.col-sm-3` you define how many of those columns your content should use. In this case 6 out 12 for *xs* screens and 3 out of 12 for *sm* screens.

You want the screen to be split into three parts for *sm*, so you need every `.thumbnail` to be contained in a `.col-sm-4`. However you also want the `.thumbnail` to be smaller, you want it to be `.col-sm-3` wide.

This doesn't map easily to Bootstrap's grid framework, as you need an offset of `(12 - 3 * 3) / 4 = 0.75` columns per part. One solution might be to define this offset yourself, by adding a `margin-left: 6.25%`.

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.col-sm-offset-3-4 {
  margin-left: 6.25%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Community Driven</h3>
        <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Community Driven</h3>
        <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"></i>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Community Driven</h3>
        <p>The more notes are added, the more knowledge is shared.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

A better solution might be to simply use a `.col-sm-4` to divide the screen into three equal parts, and to add a `<div>` around the columns content on which you add some horizontal padding.

**PS** I do think it's a good idea to rethink if you really want this. Does it really have to look exactly like this? And if so, how do you expect it to look on smaller or larger screens?